# jQuery toggle buttons to show matching content in sliding panel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sliding panel that I want to show content in. The content that I want to appear depends on the button that triggers the sliding panel. My project is growing rapidly and I would like to reusable jQuery code or perhaps a plugin. My code works, for example sake I have 6 buttons and 6 hidden divs in side of a sliding panel as shown in the image below:

[image]

Upon clicking a button i want to open the sliding panel and show the corresponding content. As of now I have done so by doing this:

**Buttons code:**

```
<div>
    <button id="p1" data-toggle="slidingPanel"></button>
    <button id="p2" data-toggle="slidingPanel"></button>
    <button id="p3" data-toggle="slidingPanel"></button>
    <button id="p4" data-toggle="slidingPanel"></button>
    <button id="p5" data-toggle="slidingPanel"></button>
</div>
```

**Sliding Panel and content divs**

```
<div class="slidingPanel">
    <div class="buttonContent" id="p1content"></div>
    <div class="buttonContent" id="p2content"></div>
    <div class="buttonContent" id="p3content"></div>
    <div class="buttonContent" id="p4content"></div>
    <div class="buttonContent" id="p5content"></div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
var slidingPanel = $('#sliding-panel');
$(body).on('click', '[data-toggle="slidingPanel"]', function() {

    //if slider is already open
    if(slidingPanel.hasClass('open')){
        slidingPanel.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500).removeClass('open');
        $('.buttonContent').hide();
        return;
    }
    //if slider is close, open slider
    slidingPanel.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500).addClass('open');
    //show content in slider based on button pressed
    $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'content').show();
});
```

Is this the best route. Is there a better way to abstract the code?

Comment: This is not working code: it contains meta-code (`...hide...`, `...show...`) and uses variables without sense in the showed context (`slidingPanel`, `test`). Should be put on hold, IMO.

Comment: @cFreed thank you i've removed the meta code and the nonsense variables.

Comment: That's better, and may be working code now, but still not clear: especially where is the element whose `id="sliding-panel"`? Looking at the image you posted, it might be the top element, while looking at the JS code suggests it'd rather be the 2nd `<div>`, which would be misspelled with `class="slidingPanel"`. In addition the HTML code doesn't reflect the expected result showed by the image. You'd better to include a snippet in your question, with the needed updates: then we'd be able to clearly know what you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

In the click event we will see right away from reading the if statement that you are performing a check to see if the `slidingPanel` is `open` by looking for a class of `open` on the element, so get rid of that first comment, you should also got rid of the `//if slider is close, open slider`  because that is also obvious from reading the code.  I am unsure of The final comment so I won't make a judgment on it.

Remove the `return` statement and make it into an if/else statement, because that is essentially what you are doing and it will read nicer.

This is what it turns into

```
var slidingPanel = $('#sliding-panel');
$(body).on('click', '[data-toggle="slidingPanel"]', function() {
    if(slidingPanel.hasClass('open')){
        slidingPanel.hide("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500).removeClass('open');
        $('.buttonContent').hide();
    } else {
        slidingPanel.show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 500).addClass('open');
        //show content in slider based on button pressed
        $('#' + $(this).attr('id') + 'content').show();
    }
});
```